# How to compare a Mongoose object to a JSON object?

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Here's my issue.

On one side I have a plain object representation of a Mongoose object.

On the other side I have a Mongoose object coming straight from a `findOne` in the database.

What I am trying to do is check if anything is different between two properties of the two object.
Let's consider this kind of model for example:

```
{
   _id: 'abc',
   id: 'abc',
   things: [{
      _id: 'def',
      id: 'def',
      other_things: [{
        _id: 'ghi',
        id: 'ghi',
        foo: 'bar'
      }]
   }]
}
```

I want to compare `myplainobject.things` to `mydbobject.things`.

But, using `underscore`, `_.isEqual(myplainobject.things, mydbobject.things)` always fails.

This is due to ids that are in the first case `string` and in the other, `ObjectID`.

While there are a lot of ways to compare an `ObjectID` to a `string`, is there an **elegant** way to compare objects?
Or do I have to implement my own solution that would loop through every subdocument and manually compare properties?

Comment: Try to use lean in query: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9952649/convert-mongoose-docs-to-json

Comment: It is not an option, I need the `save` method

Answer (score 2):

Since I do no have enough reputation at this point to add a comment to the answer by drinchev, I'll add it here instead. First, use the `toObject()` method as suggested by drinchev, and then you can use something like the answers from https://stackoverflow.com/a/14368628/3365039 (slightly modified) to ensure the keys come in the same order.

```
function compareKeys(a, b) {
    var aKeys = Object.keys(a).sort();
    var bKeys = Object.keys(b).sort();

    // Check that the objects contain the same keys.
    if (JSON.stringify(aKeys) !== JSON.stringify(bKeys)) {
        return false
    }

    // Check that the keys in each object contain the same values.
    for (const key in aKeys) {
        if (a[key] !== b[key]) {
            return false
        }
    }

    return true
}

compareKeys(mongooseModel.toObject(), jsObject)
```