# JavaScript: Deep check objects have same keys

Tags: javascript, key, javascript-objects

Question is similar to: [How can I check that two objects have the same set of property names?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14368596/how-can-i-check-that-two-objects-have-the-same-set-of-property-names) but only one difference

I want to check:

```
var objOne = {"a":"one","b":"two","c":{"f":"three_one"}};
var objTwo = {"a":"four","b":"five","c":{"f":"six_one"}};
```

have the same set of **keys** in all level?

For example `deepCheckObjKeys(objOne, objTwo)` would return `true` where `deepCheckObjKeys(objOne, objThree)` return `false`, if:

```
var objThree = {"a":"four","b":"five","c":{"g":"six_one"}};
```

Since `objThree.a.c.f` is `undefined` in **objThree**.

A function like this:

'use strict';

```
function objectsHaveSameKeys() {
   for (var _len = arguments.length, objects = Array(_len), _key = 0; _key < _len; _key++) {
      objects[_key] = arguments[_key];
   }

   var allKeys = objects.reduce(function (keys, object) {
      return keys.concat(Object.keys(object));
   }, []);
   var union = new Set(allKeys);
   return objects.every(function (object) {
      return union.size === Object.keys(object).length;
   });
}
```

only checks the first level.

**PS: objectsHaveSameKeys() ES6 equivalent:**

```
function objectsHaveSameKeys(...objects):boolean {
   const allKeys = objects.reduce((keys, object) => keys.concat(Object.keys(object)), []);
   const union = new Set(allKeys);
   return objects.every(object => union.size === Object.keys(object).length);
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I'd do a recursive check if a property's value is an object.

There's an interesting wrinkle here; actually, there are (at least) two:

- What if one of the "objects" is `null` and the other has no properties? `true` or `false`?
- What if one of the objects has `{a: null}` and the other has `{a: 17}`? `true` or `false`?
- What if one of the objects has `{a: null}` and the other has `{a: {}}`? `true` or `false`?

For the purposes of this example, I've treated `null` like an object with no properties, but it's **very** much dependent on your use case. I can think of at least two other ways to go (`null` doesn't match anything but `null`, or `null` doesn't match anything but a non-object, even if the object has no own properties) and there are probably others.

See comments:

```js
const deepSameKeys = (o1, o2) => {
    // Both nulls = same
    if (o1 === null && o2 === null) {
        return true;
    }

    // Get the keys of each object
    const o1keys = o1 === null ? new Set() : new Set(Object.keys(o1));
    const o2keys = o2 === null ? new Set() : new Set(Object.keys(o2));
    if (o1keys.size !== o2keys.size) {
        // Different number of own properties = not the same
        return false;
    }

    // Look for differences, recursing as necessary
    for (const key of o1keys) {
        if (!o2keys.has(key)) {
            // Different keys
            return false;
        }
        
        // Get the values and their types
        const v1 = o1[key];
        const v2 = o2[key];
        const t1 = typeof v1;
        const t2 = typeof v2;
        if (t1 === "object") {
            if (t2 === "object" && !deepSameKeys(v1, v2)) {
                return false;
            }
        } else if (t2 === "object") {
            // We know `v1` isn't an object
            return false;
        }
    }

    // No differences found
    return true;
};

// Checking your example
const objOne   = {"a": "one",  "b": "two",  "c": {"f": "three_one"}};
const objTwo   = {"a": "four", "b": "five", "c": {"f": "six_one"}};
const objThree = {"a": "four", "b": "five", "c": {"g": "six_one"}};

console.log("objOne vs. objTwo:         ", deepSameKeys(objOne, objTwo));        // true
console.log("objTwo vs. objThree:       ", deepSameKeys(objTwo, objThree));      // false

// `null` checks
console.log("{a: null} vs. {a: 17}      ", deepSameKeys({a: null}, {a: 17}));    // true
console.log("{a: null} vs. {a: {}}      ", deepSameKeys({a: null}, {a: {}}));    // true -- depending on your use case, you may want this to be false
console.log("{a: null} vs. {a: {x:1}}   ", deepSameKeys({a: null}, {a: {x:1}})); // false

// Differing value type check
console.log("{a: 1} vs. {a: '1'}}       ", deepSameKeys({a: 1}, {a: '1'}));      // true
```

Comment: Nice. Could I ask why you are declaring inner variables as const, and not as var ?

Comment: @ThirueswaranRajagopalan: In ES2015 and above, I default to `const`. I only use `let` if I need to change the value of the variable at some point, and I didn't need to change those. I don't use `var` at all. (Er, except I see I did when copying your `objOne` and such above. :-) )

Comment: @ThirueswaranRajagopalan: Well, me and many others. But yes, it's pretty much a style thing, although it *may* be helpful to the compiler to know that that variable won't change without having to do the necessary static analysis to prove it...

Comment: Note that if `t1` is `"object"` and either `v1` or `v2` is `null`, the recursive call will throw an exception on the `Object.keys(null)`.  You need to check for `null` either at the top of the function or before recursing.

Comment: Having implemented this myself now, I realized that arrays need to be handled specially as well. I think in most cases where you're checking the shape of an object, you'd want to treat `{ foo: [1, 2] }` and `{ foo: [] }` as having the same keys, but the code above will return `false`, since the arrays have different keys (which is true, but not really relevant).

Comment: @jdunning - Totally depends on your use case, but sure, sometimes.

Comment: Both `deepSameKeys({ a: null }, { a: 17 })` and `deepSameKeys({ a: '1' }, { a: 1 })` return `false`

Comment: @fservantdev - **Great** catch, thanks! I've updated the answer.

Comment: Is ```if (t2 === "object") {
            if (t1 === "object" && !deepSameKeys(v1, v2)) {
                return false;
            }
        }``` reachable? under what condition?

Comment: @WilliamNeely - The `return false` couldn't, no, good catch, I've updated it.

Comment: You really went the extra mile with this one **T.J.**, I appreciate it! Great example BTW. The 3 objects you choose to execute it against really made this answer great.

Comment: You know @T.J.Crowder I think this is one of the most beautiful blog reads I have had the pleasure of reading. https://thenewtoys.dev/blog/2020/07/20/kindness/

Answer (score 1):

I guess you're looking for a deep-check version of the function provided [here] :)([How can I check that two objects have the same set of property names?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14368596/how-can-i-check-that-two-objects-have-the-same-set-of-property-names)).

Below is my attempt. Please note:

- Solution does not check for null and is not bullet proof
- I haven't performance tested it. Maybe the OP or anyone else can do that and share for the community.
- I'm not a JS expert :).

```
function objectsHaveSameKeys(...objects) {
  const allKeys = objects.reduce((keys, object) => keys.concat(Object.keys(object)), [])
  const union = new Set(allKeys)
  if (union.size === 0) return true
  if (!objects.every((object) => union.size === Object.keys(object).length)) return false

  for (let key of union.keys()) {
    let res = objects.map((o) => (typeof o[key] === 'object' ? o[key] : {}))
    if (!objectsHaveSameKeys(...res)) return false
  }
  return true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create recursive function that will return all keys and check if they are equal with `every()`.

```js
var objOne = {"a":"one","b":"two","c":{"f":"three_one"}};
var objTwo = {"a":"four","b":"five","c":{"f":"six_one"}};

function checkKeys(obj1, obj2) {

  function inner(obj) {
    var result = []

    function rec(obj, c) {
      Object.keys(obj).forEach(function(e) {
        if (typeof obj[e] == 'object') rec(obj[e], c + e)
        result.push(c + e)
      })
    }
    rec(obj, '')
    return result
  }

  var keys1 = inner(obj1), keys2 = inner(obj2)
  return keys1.every(e => keys2.includes(e) && keys1.length == keys2.length)
}

console.log(checkKeys(objOne, objTwo))
```

Comment: `{a: true, bc:true, b:true}` and `{a: true, b:{c: true}}` incorrectly returns `true`

Answer (score 0):

This function checks only keys, and will check deeply until it finds something that does not match.

It's written in TypeScript:

```
function checkSameKeys(obj1: { [key: string]: any }, obj2: { [key: string]: any }) {
if (obj1 === null || !obj2 === null) {
    return false
}

const obj1Keys = Object.keys(obj1)
const obj2Keys = Object.keys(obj2)

if (obj1Keys.length !== obj2Keys.length) {
    return false
}

for (const key of obj1Keys) {
    if (obj1[key] !== null && typeof obj1[key] === 'object') {
        if (!checkSameKeys(obj1[key], obj2[key])) {
            return false
        }
    } else if (!obj2Keys.includes(key)) {
        return false
    }
}

return true
```

}