# How to check if object exists inside array of object in Angular

Tags: arrays, angular, angular-filters

I am using Angular 8. I want to check in Angular if object exists inside array of objects or not. 
My object is :

```
let objVenIns = {
                'CntNumber': 4,
                'CntMixer': 2,
                'DevicePositions': 'NA',
                'AddComments': 'NA',                
            }
```

Array of object contains other columns as well:-

```
let arrRowData = [0: {'SrNo' : 1, 'Name' : 'ABC', 'CntNumber': 1,'CntMixer': 3,'DevicePositions': 'Right','AddComments': 'NA'},
    1: {'SrNo' : 2, 'Name' : 'DEF', 'CntNumber': 4,'CntMixer': 2,'DevicePositions': 'NA','AddComments': 'NA'},
    2: {'SrNo' : 3, 'Name' : 'XYZ', 'CntNumber': 2,'CntMixer': 5,'DevicePositions': 'Left','AddComments': 'NA'}]
```

In Angular JS I used to perform following function to check if object exists in array or not:-

```
var data = $filter('filter')($scope.arrRowData, objVenIns, true)[0];
```

How to achieve such object search in Angular 8?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want get all objects which exist, then you can filter it:

```js
let objVenIns = {
'CntNumber': 4,
'CntMixer': 2,
'DevicePositions': 'NA',
'AddComments': 'NA',
};


let arrRowData = [
{'SrNo' : 1, 'Name' : 'ABC', 'CntNumber': 1,'CntMixer': 3,'DevicePositions': 'Right','AddComments': 'NA'},
{'SrNo' : 2, 'Name' : 'DEF', 'CntNumber': 4,'CntMixer': 2,'DevicePositions': 'NA','AddComments': 'NA'},
{'SrNo' : 3, 'Name' : 'XYZ', 'CntNumber': 2,'CntMixer': 5,'DevicePositions': 'Left','AddComments': 'NA'}
];

const result = arrRowData.filter(f=>
f.CntMixer === objVenIns.CntMixer &&
  f.CntNumber === objVenIns.CntNumber &&
  f.DevicePositions === objVenIns.DevicePositions &&
  f.DevicePositions === objVenIns.DevicePositions &&
  f.AddComments === objVenIns.AddComments
);

console.log(result);
console.log(result.length > 0 ? 'exists' : 'no');
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use the same [**`array.Find`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) or [`Array.Filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) with Angular as well.

```js
let arrRowData = [{'SrNo' : 1, 'Name' : 'ABC', 'CntNumber': 1,'CntMixer': 3,'DevicePositions': 'Right','AddComments': 'NA'},
    {'SrNo' : 2, 'Name' : 'DEF', 'CntNumber': 4,'CntMixer': 2,'DevicePositions': 'NA','AddComments': 'NA'},
    {'SrNo' : 3, 'Name' : 'XYZ', 'CntNumber': 2,'CntMixer': 5,'DevicePositions': 'Left','AddComments': 'NA'}];

let objVenIns = {
                'CntNumber': 4,
                'CntMixer': 2,
                'DevicePositions': 'NA',
                'AddComments': 'NA',                
            };
            
//if you want to check whole object
var isInArray = arrRowData.indexOf(objVenIns) !== -1;
console.log(isInArray);

//if you want to check by prop values

var isInArray1 = arrRowData.find(function(el){ return el.CntNumber === 4 && el.CntMixer ==2 }) !== undefined;
console.log(isInArray1);
```

Comment: I have edited my post and changed array structure. My bad that I didnt post initially. I am looking for way to check whole object. Can you pleasehelp here?

Answer (score 2):

You can identify object contains array or object using this Link [StackBlitz Link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dncg1i)
here, You can do by your custom way using **Array.isArray()**.

- **Array Structure is..**

  ```
  arrRowData = [
      {'SrNo' : 1, 'Name' : 'ABC', 'CntNumber': 1,'CntMixer': 3,'DevicePositions': 'Right','AddComments': 'NA'},
      {'SrNo' : 2, 'Name' : 'DEF', 'CntNumber': 4,'CntMixer': 2,'DevicePositions': 'NA','AddComments': 'NA'},
      {'SrNo' : 3, 'Name' : 'XYZ', 'CntNumber': 2,'CntMixer': 5,'DevicePositions': 'Left','AddComments': 'NA'},
      [{'SrNo':4}]
   ]
  ```
- **Your method to check weather array contains object or array**

  ```
  isObject(values){
     if (!Array.isArray (values) ){ return true;}
     else{ return false; }
  }
  ```
- **Your Template HTML is**

  ```
  <div *ngFor= "let section of arrRowData ">
        <ul>
             <li *ngIf="isObject(section); else printVal">
                  <span> This is Object {{section |json}} </span>
             </li>
        </ul>
        <ng-template #printVal>
              <li>  This is Array {{section | json}} </li>
        </ng-template>  
  </div>
  ```

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to check if the `object` exists, you could use [**Array#some**](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some):

```js
const arrRowData = [
  {
    SrNo: 1,
    Name: 'ABC',
    CntNumber: 1,
    CntMixer: 3,
    DevicePositions: 'Right',
    AddComments: 'NA'
  },
  {
    SrNo: 2,
    Name: 'DEF',
    CntNumber: 4,
    CntMixer: 2,
    DevicePositions: 'NA',
    AddComments: 'NA'
  },
  {
    SrNo: 3,
    Name: 'XYZ',
    CntNumber: 2,
    CntMixer: 5,
    DevicePositions: 'Left',
    AddComments: 'NA'
  }
];
const objVenIns = {
  CntNumber: 4,
  CntMixer: 2,
  DevicePositions: 'NA',
  AddComments: 'NA'
};

const areObjectEquals = (obj1, obj2) =>
  obj1.CntMixer === obj2.CntMixer &&
  obj1.CntNumber === obj2.CntNumber &&
  obj1.DevicePositions === obj2.DevicePositions &&
  obj1.DevicePositions === obj2.DevicePositions &&
  obj1.AddComments === obj2.AddComments;

const objectExistsInArray = arrRowData.some(row => areObjectEquals(row, objVenIns));

console.log('objectExistsInArray?', objectExistsInArray);
```

---

PS1: I strongly recommend you to create an interface to type your `array`, `object` and `methods`.

PS2: For a more dynamic approach where you don't need to inform which properties you want to check and you don't need to care if its properties change, I'd recommend you to look at [**this answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41802259/javascript-deep-check-objects-have-same-keys#answer-41802431).

Answer (score -1):

You can also use [Array.Propotype.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) like so:

```
const filter = arrRowData.reduce((a, e, i) => {
    if (
      e.CntMixer === objVenIns.CntMixer &&
      e.CntNumber === objVenIns.CntNumber &&
      e.DevicePositions === objVenIns.DevicePositions &&
      e.DevicePositions === objVenIns.DevicePositions &&
      e.AddComments === objVenIns.AddComments
    )
      a.push(e); return a;
}, []);  

console.log(filter)
```