# How to compare two objects but skip values and just compare keys and key types?

Tags: javascript, node.js, jestjs

I want to write unit testing using Jest for my Node.js functions and need to test if response object has some specific keys or not. Something like this:

```
expect(await mokChannelsService.getChannel(inputDto)).toEqualKeys(outputDto);

// Or just a normal function

const result = await mokChannelsService.getChannel(inputDto);
const equal = isEqualKeys(result, outputDto);
```

This `toEqualKeys` function should check equality just for keys not values. And these objects are not instances of a class. for example these two objects should be equal:

```
const object1 = {
  names: {
    firstName: '',
    lastName: '',
  },
  phone: 1,
};

const object2 = {
  names: {
    firstName: 'John',
    lastName: 'Due',
  },
  phone: 1234567890,
};

const object3 = {
  names: {
    firstName: 'John',
    lastName: 12,
  },
  mobile: '12345',
};

const result1 = toEqualKeys(object1, object2); // true
const result1 = toEqualKeys(object1, object3); // false
```

Is there any NPM packages available for this?

Comment: What are you actually testing? Why don't you know more specifically what you'll get from the function? Or why not use existing matchers, e.g. `expect(result1).toMatchObject({ phone: expect.any(String), ... })` (which would also give _substantially_ better diagnostics in a failing case than "expected false to be true")?

Comment: You are right, I know what to expect most of the time but sometimes I don't know the exact output and just care about output format

Comment: That _partially_ addresses (or is related to, at least, if not giving any actual information) one third of the comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can iterate each of the keys in `object1`, checking that the same key exists in object2 and - if the associated property in `object1` is an object, that all the keys from that object also exist in a similar object in `object2`:

```js
const object1 = {
  names: {
    firstName: '',
    lastName: '',
  },
  phone: 1,
};

const object2 = {
  names: {
    firstName: 'John',
    lastName: 'Due',
  },
  phone: 1234567890,
};

const object3 = {
  names: {
    firstName: 'John',
    lastName: 12,
  },
  mobile: '12345',
};

const toEqualKeys = (obj1, obj2) => Object.keys(obj1)
  .every(k => k in obj2 && 
    (typeof obj1[k] != 'object' || typeof obj2[k] == 'object' && toEqualKeys(obj1[k], obj2[k]))
  )
  
console.log(toEqualKeys(object1, object2))
console.log(toEqualKeys(object1, object3))
```

You can get more detail on the differences by logging differences into an array (using `reduce` to iterate the keys in the reference object). This function will return an array of errors (empty if there are none) for each comparison:

```js
const object1 = {
  names: {
    firstName: '',
    lastName: '',
  },
  phone: 1,
};

const object2 = {
  names: {
    firstName: 'John',
    lastName: 'Due',
  },
  phone: 1234567890,
};

const object3 = {
  names: {
    firstName: 'John',
    lastName: 12,
  },
  mobile: '12345',
};

const object4 = {
  names: 'John',
  mobile: '12345',
};

const object5 = {
  names: {
    firstName: 'John',
    lastName: 12,
  },
  phone: { 
    landline : '12345',
    mobile : '555'
  }
};

const object6 = {
  names: {
    firtName: 'John',
    lastName: 'Due',
  },
  phone: 1234567890,
};


const notEqualKeys = (obj1, obj2, prefix = '') => Object.keys(obj1)
  .reduce((acc, k) => {
    if (!(k in obj2)) acc.push(`key ${k} not present in obj2${prefix}`)
    if (typeof obj1[k] == 'object') {
      if (typeof obj2[k] == 'object') {
        acc = acc.concat(notEqualKeys(obj1[k], obj2[k], `${prefix}.${k}`))
      }
      else {
        acc.push(`${k} is an object in obj1${prefix} but a value in obj2${prefix}`)
      }
    }
    else if (typeof obj2[k] == 'object') {
      acc.push(`${k} is a value in obj1${prefix} but an object in obj2${prefix}`)
    }
    return acc
  }, [])
  
console.log((arr = notEqualKeys(object1, object2)).length ? arr : true)
console.log((arr = notEqualKeys(object1, object3)).length ? arr : true)
console.log((arr = notEqualKeys(object1, object4)).length ? arr : true)
console.log((arr = notEqualKeys(object1, object5)).length ? arr : true)
console.log((arr = notEqualKeys(object1, object6)).length ? arr : true)
```

Comment: @rostamiani you should unaccept this; it doesn't answer the "using Jest" part of your question

Comment: The question title is "How to compare two objects". And i can call your function in my test body. `expect(isEqualKeys(ob1,ob2).toBe(true)`. Then this answer is correct

Comment: For one thing you get exactly the problem I mentioned above - the output from the test failure doesn't give you any clue what the problem is. By flattening the value to a boolean then asserting on that you lose any useful diagnostics. Also this doesn't include the key _types_, although that's only mentioned in the title then apparently forgotten about.

Comment: @jonrsharpe You are right, maybe I will not use this function for testing. But will not remove the question. Maybe this function will be used somewhere else. Thanks

Comment: @rostamiani without the testing aspect this is just a dupe of e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/q/41802259/3001761

Comment: @jonrsharpe thanks for the feedback. FWIW I've added a second function to the answer which gives a detailed list of differences in the second object relative to the keys of the first object. Note that I don't think you can compares types of *keys*; `typeof Object.keys({ 1 : 'a'})[0]` returns `string` just as `typeof Object.keys({ '1' : 'a'})[0]` does. Or am I misinterpreting that?