# How to check if two Maps have the same key set in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, dictionary, data-structures, ecmascript-6, es6-map

Suppose to have two [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) objects, how to check if their keys sets are the same?

For example:

```
const A = new Map();
A.set('x', 123);
A.set('y', 345);

const B = new Map();
B.set('y', 567);
B.set('x', 789);

const C = new Map();
C.set('x', 121);
C.set('y', 232);
C.set('z', 434);
```

in this case both `A` and `B` maps have the same key set (which is `['x', 'y']`), while the key set of `C` is different since it has the extra key `z`.

Comment: Do you mean https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14368596/how-can-i-check-that-two-objects-have-the-same-set-of-property-names ?

Comment: you cannot call `.keys().size()` on a Map object

Comment: @SuperDJ being specific to `Map` I don't think this question is same, mainly the way of answers will be different

Comment: @FrancescoBorzì may I inquire as to the reason why you accepted my long and clunky answer instead of these others that look shorter / cleaner? (Only thing I can come up with is the complexity of the answer, mine looks more like self-explaining pseudo code)

Comment: because it's the most self-explaining answer :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could check the size and then iterate over the keys of one map and check that the other one has them too.

```js
const A = new Map();
A.set('x', 123);
A.set('y', 345);

const B = new Map();
B.set('y', 567);
B.set('x', 789);

const C = new Map();
C.set('x', 121);
C.set('y', 232);
C.set('z', 434);

function sameKeys(a, b) {
  if (a.size != b.size) {
    return false;
  }

  for (let key in a.keys()) {
    if (!b.has(key)) {
      return false;
    }
  }

  return true;
}

console.log(sameKeys(A, B));
console.log(sameKeys(A, C));
```

Answer (score 5):

Check that each map's `size` is the same, and then iterate over the `keys` of one `Map` and check that the key exists in the other as well. Utilizing `Array.prototype.every.call` means that there's no need to create an intermediate array:

```js
const A = new Map();
A.set('x', 123);
A.set('y', 345);

const B = new Map();
B.set('y', 567);
B.set('x', 789);

const C = new Map();
C.set('x', 121);
C.set('y', 232);
C.set('z', 434);

const sameKeySet = (m1, m2) => (
  m1.size === m2.size
  && Array.prototype.every.call(m1.keys(), key => m2.has(key))
);
console.log(sameKeySet(A, B));
console.log(sameKeySet(A, C));
```

Comment: Well, that looks certainly cleaner than mine. Is there a reason to use `Array.prototype` instead of `[]`.  Also can't you drop the `(... && ...)` brackets around the condition?

Comment: Utilizing `Array.prototype.every.call` means that there's no need to create an intermediate array, whereas something like `[...m1.keys()]` *would* unnecessarily create a new Array from the iterator. Yes, it would be syntactically valid to drop the parentheses, but because it's a multi-line expression, I think the parentheses make the code clearer to read.

Comment: Ah ok, I was thinking about `[].every.call` hoping that an empty array wouldn't be that much of a problem and it wouldn't look "so scary" as the `Array.prototype` =) [actually I only wanted to golf it down to two lines]

Answer (score 1):

You can convert the keys of a Map into an array by spreading the iterator returned by the `keys()` method:

```
const aKeys = [...A.keys()];
```

Then you just will have to compare all the keys arrays. For the case you show up, you can simple do:

```js
const A = new Map();
A.set('x', 123);
A.set('y', 345);

const B = new Map();
B.set('y', 567);
B.set('x', 789);

const C = new Map();
C.set('x', 121);
C.set('y', 232);
C.set('z', 434);

const aKeys = [...A.keys()];
const bKeys = [...B.keys()];
const cKeys = [...C.keys()];

console.log(aKeys.sort().toString() == bKeys.sort().toString());
console.log(aKeys.sort().toString() == cKeys.sort().toString());
console.log(bKeys.sort().toString() == cKeys.sort().toString());
```

Answer (score 1):

Basically you need to check for two things:

1. Size of both the maps, if they are unequal than simply return false.
2. If size is same than check if all the keys of map1 are present in map2,if they are than return true else return false.

```js
const A = new Map();
A.set('x', 123);
A.set('y', 345);

const B = new Map();
B.set('y', 567);
B.set('x', 789);

const C = new Map();
C.set('x', 121);
C.set('y', 232);
C.set('z', 434);

const D = new Map();
C.set('x', 121);
C.set('z', 232);


function isSame(a,b){
  if(a.size != b.size)
    return false;
 for(const [key, value] of a.entries()){
    if(!b.has(key))
      return false;
  }
  return true;
}
console.log(isSame(A,B));
console.log(isSame(A,C));
console.log(isSame(A,D));
```

Answer (score 1):

You could check the size and take the prototype of `has` and the second map as `thisArg` for checking all keys with [`Array#some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some).

This works for any types, because it does not mutate the type of the keys.

```js
const
    compare = (a, b) => a.size === b.size && [...a.keys()].some(Map.prototype.has, b),
    a = new Map([['x', 123], ['y', 345]]);
    b = new Map([['y', 567], ['x', 789]]);
    c = new Map([['x', 121], ['y', 232], ['z', 434]]);

console.log(compare(a, b));
console.log(compare(a, c));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can construct a new `Map` with both of their entries, and then compare size. Anyway you need to check the size of both of them and if its same then only you should proceed for this.

`map1.size.size` **===** `map2.size &&`

`new Map([...map1, ...map2])).size` **===** `map1.size` *//or map2.size*

Let's create a working example:

```js
const A = new Map();
A.set('x', 123);
A.set('y', 345);

const B = new Map();
B.set('y', 567);
B.set('x', 789);

const C = new Map();
C.set('x', 121);
C.set('y', 232);
C.set('z', 434);

let compareMap = (m1, m2) => (
  m1.size === m2.size &&
  (new Map([...m1, ...m2])).size === m1.size
)

console.log('Compare A & B: ', compareMap(A, B));
console.log('Compare A & C: ', compareMap(A, C));
console.log('Compare B & C: ', compareMap(B, C));
```

Comment: In case you didn't know: Code-Snippets have an inbuild autoformat button: https://i.stack.imgur.com/RwGHH.png

Comment: Thanks for the alignment edit. However, people should focus on the content (at least when it's 2-liner) but yes, alignment dose matter to a better have visibility of the actual  content!

Answer (score 0):

Here's a one liner wrapped in a TypeScript'ized function

```
function sameKeys(a: Map<string, string>, b: Map<string, string>): boolean {
    return a.size === b.size && [...a.keys()].every(key => b.has(key))
}
```