# how to compare if two objects have the same fields (same schema)

Tags: javascript, node.js

I receive a JSON object through an HTTP request.I just want to check if that object has *only* the fields that I want, don't need to check their value.
I did this:

```
function checkObject(o1, o2) {
  for (const p1 in o1) {
     for (const p2 in o2) {
      if (o1.hasOwnProperty(p2) === false) {
        return false;
      }
      if (o2.hasOwnProperty(p1) === false) {
        return false;
      }
    }
   }
  return true;
}
```

This is the valid object. I want to accept only requests with this body, don't care about the values.

```
const validObject = {
  country: '',
  name: '',
  zip: '',
  //etc
};
```

after this i do an if statement like:

```
if(checkObject(validObject, receivedObject)){
    //do stuff here
}else{
    //reject the request
}
```

Ok this works, but it is too ugly. It does not pass the *lint* test and there are too many for loops. What do you think? is there an alternative to do the same thing?
Thank you!!

Comment: First get the keys: `const keys1 = Object.keys(o1)`. Next, sort them alphabetically: `keys1.sort((a, b) => a > b)`. Finally, stringify: `const json1 = JSON.stringify(keys1);`. The resulting two strings should be identical.

Comment: Also, depending on the library you are using to write your http endpoints, it may be possible that it already includes a way to validate the content you receive. Chris G's idea will work pretty good.

Comment: Duplicate: [How can I check that two objects have the same set of property names?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14368596/how-can-i-check-that-two-objects-have-the-same-set-of-property-names) cc @GuerricP

Comment: Thak you guys! @ChrisG yeah that works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're interested there is a spec for [JSON schema validation](https://json-schema.org/specification.html), and there are implementations for JavaScript like [ajv](https://github.com/ajv-validator/ajv).

Now I think this would be too much for what you need. The implementation of `checkObject` could be:

```js
const valid = {
  foo: '',
  bar: ''
}

const okay = {
  bar: '',
  foo: ''
}

const notEnough = {
  foo: ''
}

const tooMuch = {
  foo: '',
  bar: '',
  foobar : ''
}

function checkObject(validObject, receivedObject) {
  const validKeys = Object.keys(validObject);
  const receivedKeys = Object.keys(receivedObject);
  return validKeys.length === receivedKeys.length
    && validKeys.every(value => ~receivedKeys.indexOf(value));
}

console.log(checkObject(valid, okay));
console.log(checkObject(valid, notEnough));
console.log(checkObject(valid, tooMuch));
```

Comment: Doesn't work if the objects' keys are in different order, eg `const okay = {bar: '', foo: ''}`

Comment: @James thanks for pointing out, I've fixed that

Comment: Curious what is the `~receivedKeys` tilde doing in this case @GuerricP

Comment: @konsalex it's just a JavaScript hack which consists in using the [bitwise not operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_NOT) in order to return `0` (which is falsy) when the input is `-1`. It returns truthy values (numbers different than `0`) in other cases

Answer (score 0):

here is a [lodash](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15) version

```
import _ from "lodash"


function checkObject(o1,o2){
  return !_(o1).keys().intersection(_.keys(o2)).isEmpty();
}
```